# How does async I/O on /proc filesystem works?

Tags: c++, linux, asynchronous, asio

I've been working on some project, where I use standalone `asio` for async file reading/writing, but I also need to get some system statistics like CPU usage, network usage (e.g. `rx` and `tx`) and more. I've achieved this by reading `/proc/stat` for CPU and `/proc/net/dev` for network using `asio::random_access_file` which uses POSIX `read` and `write` calls for sync I/O and `io_uring` for async I/O. For me, it's clear why do people use async I/O, but I'm curious what advantages and disadvantages can be when doing async I/O on `/proc` fs, because it's not the same thing as usual filesystem. Does it even have sense to use async with `/proc` together?

Comment: Read and write from/to `/proc` takes some time (OS kernel operations) and it really depends on how often you need to make requests to `/proc` and what kind of architecture your application has. Does it has another task to run while waiting IO to complete? I would say tests could answer your question in your particular use case.